# Unknown numbers of groups up to isomorphism of various prime powers

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

Let $\mathrm{gnu}(n)$ denote the number of groups of order $n$.

I'm aware that we know $\mathrm{gnu}(2^{10})$, but not $\mathrm{gnu}(2^{11})$. Also, we know functions describing $\mathrm{gnu}(p^{1}), \dots, \mathrm{gnu}(p^{7})$ for $p$ prime in terms of PORC functions.

[This](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2023.2169706) paper states $\mathrm{gnu}(3^{9})$ is known. I can't find anything on $\mathrm{gnu}(3^{10})$. Presumably, this is unknown as of December 2023, is that correct?

I can't find any sources for $\mathrm{gnu}(5^{8})$ or higher prime bases to the power of $8$. Are these, as of December 2023, also unknown?